# How can I select a console color using the array?

Tags: c#

So I'm really new to C# as you can tell. I want to make the background color of the console / command prompt change randomly, I figured the best way to do this would be to select a random number using random.next(), since Console.BackgroundColor actually labels all the colors with numbers as well as strings,

It says red is 12, blue is 9, I tried doing these but they don't compile:

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor(myIndex);
Console.BackgroundColor = myIndex;
```

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) the number to a `ConsoleColor`, as that's [the type that BackgroundColor needs to be set to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.backgroundcolor) - here's an example:

```
int myIndex = 9; // ConsoleColor.Blue
Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)myIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ConsoleColor. just like below,

```
  Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
```

You can also add condition like

```
if(myIndex == 12)
     Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
else if (myIndex == 9)
     Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, You are looking for a method to set random background color, according to @stuartd answer here is the code:

```
    public static ConsoleColor RandomConsoleColor()
    {
        return (ConsoleColor)new Random().Next(0, 15);
    }
```

Then you can run it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = RandomConsoleColor(); // <<-- call
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to set random Background Color(Ctrl+c to Exit)");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Here is the reference of the integer to color code-names:

```
Black = 0
DarkBlue = 1
DarkGreen = 2
DarkCyan = 3
DarkRed = 4
DarkMagenta = 5
DarkYellow = 6
Gray = 7
DarkGray = 8
Blue = 9
Green = 10
Cyan = 11
Red = 12
Magenta = 13
Yellow = 14
White = 15
```